# How to draw two charts in same figure using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I want to draw two charts (one in left and other one in right) using tikz. This is my code but it only can draw one chart in a figure. Thanks so much

```
\begin{figure}[htb] 
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}


    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        xlabel = X,
        xmin = -0.3,xmax = 4.3,
        ymin = 0, ymax = 10,
        axis x line* = bottom,
        axis y line* = left,
        ylabel= Y,
        width= 0.9\textwidth,
        height = 0.6\textwidth,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        bar width = 0.5mm,
        xticklabels = \empty,
        extra x ticks = {0,1,2,3,4},
        extra x tick labels = {0,1,2,3,4},
        legend pos=north east,
        ]

        \addplot coordinates {
            (0,2)
            (1,6)
            (2,6)
            (3,6)
            (4,6)
        };
        \addplot coordinates {
            (0,5)
            (1,5)
            (2,5)
            (3,5)
            (4,5)
        };
        \addlegendimage{empty legend}
        \addlegendentry{$A$}
        \addlegendentry{$B$}
    \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{chart}
\end{figure}
```

Expected output likes
[image]

Comment: If you want two figure captions, put each tikzpicture and its caption into a minipage {0.5\textwidth} wide.  Do not add a blank line of extra space between the two.

Comment: It is good idea. I think left figure will be (a) and right figure will be (b) and then the figure contains two sub figure will be main caption. Could you do it for me?

Comment: Sorry, My english is bad. I have used above code to draw a chart. It is fine. Now, I want to draw the other chart (left side) but same figure. May be your work may not as what I expect

Comment: I have update the figure that I expect in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shows how to add two (subcaption package) subfigures to a figure.  There are many different packages with subfigures, but they are all glorified minipages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}% older version
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb] 
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        xlabel = X,
        xmin = -0.3,xmax = 4.3,
        ymin = 0, ymax = 10,
        axis x line* = bottom,
        axis y line* = left,
        ylabel= Y,
        width= 0.9\textwidth,
        height = 0.6\textwidth,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        bar width = 0.5mm,
        xticklabels = \empty,
        extra x ticks = {0,1,2,3,4},
        extra x tick labels = {0,1,2,3,4},
        legend pos=north east,
        ]

        \addplot coordinates {
            (0,2)
            (1,6)
            (2,6)
            (3,6)
            (4,6)
        };
        \addplot coordinates {
            (0,5)
            (1,5)
            (2,5)
            (3,5)
            (4,5)
        };
        \addlegendimage{empty legend}
        \addlegendentry{$A$}
        \addlegendentry{$B$}
    \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Subfigure}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        xlabel = X,
        xmin = -0.3,xmax = 4.3,
        ymin = 0, ymax = 10,
        axis x line* = bottom,
        axis y line* = left,
        ylabel= Y,
        width= 0.9\textwidth,
        height = 0.6\textwidth,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        bar width = 0.5mm,
        xticklabels = \empty,
        extra x ticks = {0,1,2,3,4},
        extra x tick labels = {0,1,2,3,4},
        legend pos=north east,
        ]

        \addplot coordinates {
            (0,2)
            (1,6)
            (2,6)
            (3,6)
            (4,6)
        };
        \addplot coordinates {
            (0,5)
            (1,5)
            (2,5)
            (3,5)
            (4,5)
        };
        \addlegendimage{empty legend}
        \addlegendentry{$A$}
        \addlegendentry{$B$}
    \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Subfigure}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Main Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks.  I accepted your answer because it has less modification. I have two things want to add: (1) the legend A or B has two rectangular, can we make it as one rectangular? (2) Can we reduce the margin between A and B in the chart? I want them close as much as possible

Comment: (1) The legend can be placed outside the axes.  It can even be implemented as a \ref anywhere in the document.  See pages 264-265 of the pgfplots mnaual

Comment: (2) They are currently centered in each subfigure. Using \raggedleft and \raggedright (or inserting \hfill to the outsides) one can un-center them.  To move the captions, you will need to shrink the subfigures.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a proposal with group plots.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
      group name=my plots,
      group size=2 by 1,
      ylabels at=edge left,
      xlabels at=edge bottom,
      horizontal sep=2cm,
    },width= 0.45\textwidth,
     height = 0.6\textwidth,
    ]

    \nextgroupplot[
    axis x line=top,
        ybar,
        xlabel = $X$,
        xmin = -0.3,xmax = 4.5,
        ymin = 0, ymax = 10,
        axis x line* = bottom,
        axis y line* = left,
        ylabel= $Y$,       
        ymajorgrids = true,
        bar width = 3mm,
        xticklabels = \empty,
        extra x ticks = {0,1,2,3,4},
        extra x tick labels = {0,1,2,3,4},
        legend pos=north east,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {
            (0,2)
            (1,6)
            (2,6)
            (3,6)
            (4,6)
        };
        \addplot coordinates {
            (0,2)
            (1,6)
            (2,6)
            (3,6)
            (4,6)
        };
        \addlegendimage{empty legend}
        \addlegendentry{$A$}
        \addlegendentry{$B$}
    \nextgroupplot[
    axis x line=top,
        ybar,
        xlabel =$X$,
        xmin = -0.3,xmax = 4.5,
        ymin = 0, ymax = 10,
        axis x line* = bottom,
        axis y line* = left,
        ylabel=$Y$,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        bar width = 3mm,
        xticklabels = \empty,
        extra x ticks = {0,1,2,3,4},
        extra x tick labels = {0,1,2,3,4},
        legend pos=north east,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {
            (0,5)
            (1,5)
            (2,5)
            (3,5)
            (4,5)
        };
        \addplot coordinates {
            (0,2)
            (1,6)
            (2,6)
            (3,6)
            (4,6)
        };
        \addlegendimage{empty legend}
        \addlegendentry{$A$}
        \addlegendentry{$B$}
    \end{groupplot} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]